# "Attempt to present Xamarin_Forms_Platform_iOS_ModalWrapper whose view is not in the window hierarchy" error with UIImagePickerController

Tags: c#, .net, swift, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have an Xamarin.Forms-based app which runs on Android and iOS. Right now, I am implementing the feature of selecting images from the camera roll and uploading it to our server. Therefore, I am writing platform-specific code for iOS, which is where the error occurs.

I am calling the UIImagePickerController from a platform-specific renderer for iOS. It opens normally. But when tapping on an image in the UIImagePickerController nothing happens, except Visual Studio showing a message in the debug console:

*"Warning: Attempt to present Xamarin_Forms_Platform_iOS_ModalWrapper: 0x155a7ed00 on Xamarin_Forms_Platform_iOS_PlatformRenderer: 0x153ead6a0 whose view is not in the window hierarchy!"*

I googled and found somebody writing a function called "GetVisibleViewController" which i adapted to my project (you can see it below). On the ViewController which that function returns, I call the PresentModalViewController() method. Unfortunately, it is not working either. It is not possible to select a photo.

```cs
private void ChoosePhoto()
{
    _imagePicker = new UIImagePickerController()
    {
        SourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary,
        MediaTypes = new string[] { UTType.Image }
    };

    _imagePicker.FinishedPickingMedia += delegate (object sender, UIImagePickerMediaPickedEventArgs e)
    {
        var fileName = eopAppLibrary.Tools.GetTimestampJpegFileName("ScanToEop_iOS");
        var jpegImageData = e.OriginalImage.AsJPEG();
        var jpegBytes = jpegImageData.ToArray();

        Events.RaiseFilePreviewNeeded(this, jpegBytes, fileName);
    };

    _imagePicker.Canceled += delegate (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _imagePicker.DismissModalViewController(true);
    };

    var viewController = GetVisibleViewController();
    viewController.PresentModalViewController(_imagePicker, true);
}
```

```cs
UIViewController GetVisibleViewController(UIViewController controller = null)
{
    controller = controller ?? UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController;

    if (controller.PresentedViewController == null)
    {
        return controller;
    }

    if (controller.PresentedViewController is UINavigationController)
    {
        return ((UINavigationController)controller.PresentedViewController).VisibleViewController;
    }

    if (controller.PresentedViewController is UITabBarController)
    {
        return ((UITabBarController)controller.PresentedViewController).SelectedViewController;
    }

    return GetVisibleViewController(controller.PresentedViewController);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I implemented this by using James Montemagno's Media Plugin library (available over NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.Media) and Permissions Plugin (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.Permissions).

I wrote the following code for this:

```
private async Task ChoosePhoto()
{
    var permission = await CheckCameraRollPermission();

    if (permission == PermissionStatus.Granted)
    {
        await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

        // Show image picker dialog
        var file = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.PickMediaOptions()
        {
            ModalPresentationStyle = Plugin.Media.Abstractions.MediaPickerModalPresentationStyle.OverFullScreen
        });

        if (file != null)
        {
            // Image has been selected
            using (var stream = file.GetStream())
            {
                using (var memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
                {
                    stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);

                    var fileBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();

                    // DO WHATEVER YOU WANT TO DO WITH THE SELECTED IMAGE AT THIS POINT
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private async Task<PermissionStatus> CheckCameraRollPermission()
{
    // Check permission for image library access
    var permission = await PermissionsImplementation.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Photos);

    if (permission != PermissionStatus.Granted)
    {
        // Permission has not been granted -> if permission has been requested before and the user did not grant it, show message and return the permission
        var message = "";

        switch (permission)
        {
            case PermissionStatus.Denied:
            case PermissionStatus.Restricted:
                message = "Unfortunately, you did not grant permission to access the camera roll. If you want to change this, you can do so in the system settings of your device.";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
        {
            // Message available -> Display alert and return the permission
            var alert = UIAlertController.Create("Permission not granted", message, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
            alert.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("OK", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, null));

            PresentViewController(alert, true, null);
            return permission;
        }

        // In all other cases, request the permission
        await PermissionsImplementation.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(Permission.Photos);

        // Check for permission one more time and return it
        permission = await PermissionsImplementation.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Photos);
    }

    return permission;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar issue and here is what we came up with:

```
    var topViewController = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController;
    var controllerToPresentWith = topViewController.VisibleViewController();
    controllerToPresentWith.PresentModalViewController(_imagePicker, true);
```

and then

```
    ...
    public static UIViewController VisibleViewController(this UIViewController controller)
    {
        if (controller == null)
            return null;

        if (controller is UINavigationController navController)
        {
            return navController.VisibleViewController();
        }
        else if (controller is UITabBarController tabController)
        {
            tabController.SelectedViewController?.VisibleViewController();
        }
        else
        {
            var vc =  controller.PresentedViewController?.VisibleViewController();
            if (vc != null)
                return vc;
        }
        return controller;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, that did not solve the problem. Maybe it has someting to do with the tab page the view is a child of...

Comment: might be @Sebastian, in that case, you have to traverse your hierarchy deeper or more thoroughly. You can do it in debug mode, using "Immediate" window